# stringr: extract words containing a specific word

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Consider this simple example

```
dataframe <- data_frame(text = c('WAFF;WOFF;WIFF200;WIFF12',
                                 'WUFF;WEFF;WIFF2;BIGWIFF'))

> dataframe
# A tibble: 2 x 1
                      text
                     <chr>
1 WAFF;WOFF;WIFF200;WIFF12
2  WUFF;WEFF;WIFF2;BIGWIFF
```

Here I want to extract the words containing `WIFF`, that is I want to end up with a dataframe like this

```
> output
# A tibble: 2 x 1
            text
           <chr>
1 WIFF200;WIFF12
2  WIFF2;BIGWIFF
```

I tried to use

```
dataframe %>% 
  mutate( mystring = str_extract(text, regex('\bwiff\b', ignore_case=TRUE)))
```

but this only retuns NAs. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to remove all words containing `WIFF` and the trailing `;` if there is any. Use

```
> dataframedataframe <- data.frame(text = c('WAFF;WOFF;WIFF200;WIFF12', 'WUFF;WEFF;WIFF2;BIGWIFF'))
> dataframe$text <- str_replace_all(dataframe$text, "(?i)\\b(?!\\w*WIFF)\\w+;?", "")
> dataframe
            text
1 WIFF200;WIFF12
2  WIFF2;BIGWIFF
```

The pattern `(?i)\\b(?!\\w*WIFF)\\w+;?` matches:

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive inline modifier
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\\w*WIFF)` - the negative lookahead fails any match where a word contains `WIFF` anywhere inside it
- `\\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `;?` - an optional `;` (`?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the pattern it modifies)

If for some reason you want to use `str_extract`, note that your regex could not work because [`\bWIFF\b` matches a whole word WIFF](https://regex101.com/r/H83j0v/1) and nothing else. You do not have such words in your DF. You may use [`"(?i)\\b\\w*WIFF\\w*\\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/H83j0v/2) to match any words with `WIFF` inside (case insensitively) and use `str_extract_all` to get multiple occurrences, and do not forget to join the matches into a single "string":

```
> df <- data.frame(text = c('WAFF;WOFF;WIFF200;WIFF12', 'WUFF;WEFF;WIFF2;BIGWIFF'))
> res <- str_extract_all(df$text, "(?i)\\b\\w*WIFF\\w*\\b")
> res
[[1]]
[1] "WIFF200" "WIFF12" 

[[2]]
[1] "WIFF2"   "BIGWIFF"

> df$text <- sapply(res, function(s) paste(s, collapse=';'))
> df
            text
1 WIFF200;WIFF12
2  WIFF2;BIGWIFF
```

You may "shrink" the code by placing `str_extract_all` into the `sapply` function, I separated them for better visibility.

Comment: thanks Wiktor very nice. you seem to imply that it is easier to replace the non-matching patterns rather than extracting the ones that match? why?

Comment: @Noobie: I did not say that. It is up to you to decide what is easier.

Comment: I mean your solution is great, but do you know my `str_extract` does not work at all?

Comment: @Noobie: My logic is simple: if your character vectors contain "strings" with "words" that do not necessarily have `WIFF` inside,  a matching approach means splitting/extracting or matching all valid occurrences and then joining them back. It looks cumbesome to me (although it is not what I thought when I wrote the answer). Your approach could not work because [`\bWIFF\b` matches a whole word `WIFF`](https://regex101.com/r/H83j0v/1) and nothing else. You do not have such words in your DF.

Comment: OK got it thanks. do you see an easy way to use `str_extract` here? Just trying to learn some regex skills here :)

Comment: I forgot to make the pattern case insensitive, added that bit now.

Answer (score 4):

A classic, non-regex approach via base R would be,

```
sapply(strsplit(me$text, ';', fixed = TRUE), function(i) 
                              paste(grep('WIFF', i, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE), collapse = ';'))

#[1] "WIFF200;WIFF12" "WIFF2;BIGWIFF"
```